# Previewing the live streaming video from the worldcam travel API

Tags: android

Can anybody tell me how can i **play** the **live streaming** cam video from this response of **API world-cam**..

I am getting problem to **preview** the video from this link directly :

```
{
  "live": {
    "available": true,
    "embed": "https://api.lookr.com/embed/player/1485691420/live"
  },
  "day": {
    "available": true,
    "link": "https://www.lookr.com/lookout/1485691420#action-play-day",
    "embed": "https://api.lookr.com/embed/player/1485691420/day"
  },
  "month": {
    "available": true,
    "link": "https://www.lookr.com/lookout/1485691420#action-play-month",
    "embed": "https://api.lookr.com/embed/player/1485691420/month"
  },

}
```

Comment: hi welcome to stackoverflow , pls read : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and if you want best and fast solving you will ask with nice quality

Answer (score 0):

If you wish **stream and play** Video in **Android App** , you can use this **library** : [Vitamio Library](https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle)

Comment: can u refer me some example of vitamio lib